# Configure Password Encryption via REST for GeoServer

Tags: rest, geoserver

By default, GeoServer uses [weak password-based encryption](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/security/passwd.html) for the default usergroup and shows a hint in the web administration interface to change it to Hash (Digest). This can be done in the interface under Users, Groups, Roles > User Group Services > default > Passwords.

I would like to change the password encryption via REST. Is that possible? I haven't found any matching endpoint in the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/master/en/user/rest/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that functionality is provided via the REST API. If you would like to add it we would welcome a PR adding the functionality.